# How to expose a REST service from HDFS?

Tags: rest, hadoop, hive, hdfs, impala

My project requires to expose a REST service from HDFS, currently we are processing huge amount of data on HDFS, we are using MR jobs to store all the data from HDFS to Apache-Impala database for our reporting needs.

At present we have a REST endpoint hitting the Impala database but the problem is the Impala database is not fully updated with the latest data from HDFS.

We run MR jobs periodically to update the Impala database, but as we know the MR will consume lot-of time due to this we are not able to perform real-time queries on HDFS.

Use case/Scenario : Okay let me explain in detail; We have one application called "duct" built on top of hadoop, this application process huge amount of data and creates individual archives (serialized avro files) on HDFS for every run.We have another application (lets say the name is Avro-To-Impala) which takes these AVRO archives as input, process them using MR jobs and populates a new schema on Impala for every "duct" run.This tool reads the AVRO files and creates and populates the tables on Impala schema. Inorder to expose the data outside (REST endpoint) we are relaying on the Impala database.In this case whenever we have output from "duct" eventually to update the database we explicitly run "Avro-To-Impala" tool.This processing is taking long time because of this the REST endpoint returning obsolete or old data to the consumers of the web service.

Can anyone suggest solution for this kind of problem ?

Many Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand what is your problem... _"store all the data from HDFS to Impala database"_ >> but the Impala database *also* stores its data files on HDFS! What is the purpose of the _"MR jobs"_: compute aggregates? deduplicate? convert from row format to columnar format i.e. Parquet?

Comment: _"run MR jobs periodically to update the Impala database ... MR will consume lot-of time ... database is not fully updated with the latest data ... not able to perform real-time queries"_ >> yeah, that was why the Lambda architecture was introduced in 2013. Nowadays it's more fashionable to go full-streaming, with processors that can be queried to deliver current values of aggregates (cf. Kafka Streams for instance).

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter , Thanks for your update, I edited the question and elaborated the use case , can you have look ?